# Replacing an object by a deserialized version of it, and preserving references

Tags: vb.net, serialization, reference, deserialization, reference-type

Say I have an object of my custom class, called `AppSettings`, which has various properties that hold both value types (integers, doubles, strings, etc.) and reference types (arrays, other custom objects, etc.). Some of these custom objects have their own custom objects, so the path down to some of the value type properties can go very deep.

For example:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class AppSettings
    Public Property windowHeight As Integer = 600
    Public Property windowWidth As Integer = 800
    Public Property defaultLengthUnit As Unit = Units.meters
    Public Property defaultAngleUnit As Unit = Units.degrees
End Class
```

Where Unit class is defined as:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Unit
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Abbreviation As String
    Public Property Scale As Double
End Class
```

And Units module is defined as:

```
Public Module Units
    Public meters As New Unit With {
        .Name = "Meters",
        .Abbreviation = "m.",
        .Scale = 1
    }
Public degrees As New Unit With {
    .Name = "Degrees",
    .Abbreviation = "°",
    .Scale = 1
    }
End Module
```

Some other code might refer or bind to some of the reference type properties, or their internal properties. Now, let's say I provide a way for the user to save current state of AppSettings by serializing it into XML:

```
Public Sub SerializeAppSettings(ByVal filename As String)
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
        Dim xmls As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(AppSettings))
        xmls.Serialize(sw, appSettings)
    End Using
End Sub
```

and then load them back (by deserializing) at any time while running the application:

```
Public Function DeserializeAppSettings(ByVal filename As String) As AppSettings
    If Not File.Exists(filename) Then Return Nothing
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename)
        Dim xmls As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(AppSettings))
        Return TryCast(xmls.Deserialize(sr), AppSettings)
    End Using
End Function
```

It is called like so:

```
AppSettings = DeserializeAppSettings(settingsFilePath)
```

The problem here is that all the references to AppSettings that other objects and bindings have, are now broken, because deserialization replaces the old instance of `AppSettings` with a completely new instance, and the references are not transferred to it.

It appears that this doesn't break references to value-type properties (like `windowHeight`, which is Integer), but it definitely breaks references to reference-type properties, like `defaultLengthUnit`. So for example, if some other object or WPF control is referring/binding to, say, `AppSettings.defaultLengthUnit.scaleToBaseUnit`, it doesn't work anymore.

I wonder, how can I fix this, so that deserialization would replace the old instance of `AppSettings` and transfer all the references from it to the new instance that it generated?

As I understand it, there are three ways to go about it:

1. Replace the old instance with an new one in the exact same memory allocation, with the same internal ID, which would probably be too hacky, and I'm not sure if at all possible.
2. Another way would be for the `DeserializeAppSettings` function to overwrite each property value of the current `AppSettings` instance, one by one, by the deserialized values. However, since some properties of `AppSettings` are objects, which have their own objects, which have their own objects (and so on), I would basically need to type out all the hierarchy tree in that `DeserializeAppSettings` function to get down to the value type properties. And every time I would need to add or remove any property in the `AppSettings` class (or in any class that is used in it's properties), I would also need to manually update the parsing code in `DeserializeAppSettings` function. This is seriously unmaintainable.
3. Lastly, it would probably be possible to automate this value replacement through reflection, but reflection is very slow, and generally discouraged if there is any other option.

I hope I am missing something obvious here. Any suggestions on how to transfer all the references to `AppSettings` when the old instance of it is replaced with a new one through deserialization?

EDIT: Updated the code to include all the relevant classes.

Comment: I call that function on the load of application, and also on the button click ("Restore settings"). I forgot to add the <Serializable()> attribute. But the serialization still seems to succeed... I added that attribute to the AppSettings class, but nothing seems to have changed in the behavior. I am unsure when this attribute is needed, and what does it change in this context.

Comment: Please add the serialize routine. `SerializeAppSettings`.

Comment: @dr.null ok, I added it to my question, please check now :)

Comment: OK. Use the `XmlSerializer` ctor that accepts an array of extra types. Ex. `Dim xmls = New XmlSerializer(GetType(AppSettings), {GetType(Unit)})`. Try and see how it goes.

Comment: Hm... I tried it (extended that declaration exactly how you wrote it, both on the serialize and deserialize function), but it didn't change anything :/

Comment: I don't know. Anyways, Make sure that you have a single `AppSettings` instance either from the _deserialize_ routine or by instantiating a new instance, make sure that your classes don't have non-serializable objects, update the properties of that single instance before the serialization. Btw. Use a different instance name to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I am already doing all of that which you mentioned, except the last point - using a different instance name. You see, that is the whole point - I want to replace the original instance with the instance produced by deserialization, and since the whole application is referencing that old instance, named AppSettings, I specifically want the new instance to take it's place with the same name.

Comment: Do the underlying types, "the path down", need to have the serializable attribute?

Comment: @Mary - to my knowledge,, XML serialization doesn't need that attribute at all, but for testing, I added that attribute to everything, on every level. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: True. But we need a reproducible code to do some tests rather than giving some guesses. What are these `Units`, `meters`, `degrees` fellows? Posting all the serializable objects definitely will help. Meanwhile, open the generated XML file with Notepad or Notepad++ and see whether the keys and values are there.

Comment: @dr.null - sorry, I updated the question now with all these missing details. In the XML file, I can see that everything is included and serialized properly, with correct hierarchy tree. No missing properties or anything. And when that AppSettings object is deserialized, the resulting object also has all the correct data from the XML file - nothing is missing, no null values or anything. It's just that the application doesn't have the references to this new object or it's properties anymore.

Comment: Re 2 and 3, the XML serialization/deserialization is already using reflection.  I think the main issue is that you would need to write your own deserialization code, but I don't think that would require an excessive amount of effort (I wrote my own in ~2-3 days because I wanted to work with `XElement` types instead of `XmlElement` types).